# How to add a cursor/text position indicator to a <textarea> controlled by javascript?

Tags: html, javascript, css

I am making a typewriter like website ([here](https://docs.thkc.space/cool/typewritter/)) that uses a textarea and javascript (from button clicks) to add/remove from the textarea.

The next thing I want to add is an indicator to show where the next update (insert/remove) will be so I guess its always at the of the textarea value.

The key details that clash with other solutions are

- The textarea is disabled (+ its a textarea and not a p tag)
- Users add characters by using the buttons and not by typing with their keyboards
- The user isn't selecting or has a selection while typing
- Some solutions involve css that break the website

This is how I insert characters

```
function insert(char) {
    document.getElementById("textarea").value += char
    update()
}
```

to the textarea + a button

```
<textarea id="textarea" class="textarea" disabled>
</textarea>

<a onclick="insert('1')"> 
    <div class="letterbox">
        <p class="typewritter">1</p>
    </div> 
</a>
```

(btw I know I spelled typewriter wrong on the website and will fix that later)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a custom insertion point (the blinking line) you can do that by adding and removing a chosen symbol ('|' for example) from the text with an interval. Perhaps something like this would do:

```js
const insertionSymbol = '|';
const blinkInterval = 1000; // time in ms between insertion point updates
let blinking = true; // whether the insertion line is hidden
let textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
setInterval(function() {
    if(blinking) {
        textarea.value += insertionSymbol;
    } else {
        textarea.value = textarea.value.slice(0,-1);
    }
    blinking = !blinking;
}, blinkInterval);
```

that would require you to change the insert and delete functions:

```js
function insert(char) {
    if(blinking) {
        textarea.value += char;
    } else {
        // inserting the character before the insertion point by removing the insertion point temporarily 
        textarea.value = textarea.value.slice(0,-1) + char + insertionSymbol; 
    }
}
function delete() {
    if(blinking) {
        textarea.value = textarea.slice(0,-1);
    } else {
        // deleting the character before the insertion point by removing the insertion point temporarily 
        textarea.value = textarea.value.slice(0,-2) + insertionSymbol; 
    }
}
```

This idea can be expanded. for example, if you want to add a insertion point cool-down (i.e. change the insertion point to stay visible for some time after an update, like you see in most text editors), you can change the interval to run every millisecond, and add a timer for the next update. like this:

```js
// ... all the variable definitions like before
let timer = blinkInterval;
setInterval(function() {
    timer --;
    if(timer == 0) {
        if(blinking) {
            textarea.value += insertionSymbol;
        } else {
            textarea.value = textarea.value.slice(0,-1);
        }
        blinking = !blinking;
        timer = blinkInterval;
    }
}, 1);
function insert(char) {
    if(blinking) {
        blinking = false;
        textarea.value += char + insertionSymbol;
    } else {
        // inserting the character before the insertion point by removing the insertion point temporarily 
        textarea.value = textarea.value.slice(0,-1) + char + insertionSymbol; 
    }
    timer = blinkInterval;
}
function delete() {
    if(blinking) {
        blinking = false;
        textarea.value = textarea.slice(0,-1) + insertionSymbol;
    } else {
        // deleting the character before the insertion point by removing the insertion point temporarily 
        textarea.value = textarea.value.slice(0,-2) + insertionSymbol; 
    }
    timer = blinkInterval;
}
```

Note: I'm writing the code blindly (I didn't run it to see if it works) so I'm sorry in advance for any mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

I think overriding textarea attributes is meaningless. The indicator that you want is already in it's characteristic.

Remove the `disabled` tag from your `textarea` and just block the keyboard pressing with the below code snippet. [because not using keyboard typing is your feature]

```
document.onkeydown = function (e)  {
  return false;
}
```

If you want to you can bind the function to focus action of the `textarea`.

Comment: I would suggest just adding a `pointer-events:none;` instead of adding more js

Comment: @AgamemnonKatradis instead of 'disabled'? This will not solve the problem. 'pointer-event:none;' will remove the indicator from the textarea. As I understand, he wants to add indicator.

Comment: Ok, I tried that out it works but is there a way to prevent people from moving the cursor by clicking on previous characters while still letting them select part/all and copy later?

Comment: Yes, certainly. But this is little more harder. You can prevent click action in Javascript easily but this will block select part/all of text also. You'll have to separate these two action using Javascript and I'm not sure that will work on mobile devices smoothly. If you can't solve this feature while doing it, it may be more helpful for everyone to ask it as a another question.

Comment: Hmmm ok
I'll look around for a way to separate them if not I'll ask a new question
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion on this would be to have the textarea active, NOT disabled and always on focus. This way you will have the blinking effect you want. Then have a `pointer-events:none` css on the textarea so no one can click on it and you have the blink you want. So my steps would be:

1. Remove `disabled` from textarea
2. Add `pointer-events:none` css rule to the textarea
3. On the `update()` function I observe add either a `focus` or a `click` event so the textarea gets focus on each `insert()`

Comment: Add `pointer-events:none` css rule to the textarea
I did this and it solved [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576716/how-to-add-a-curser-text-position-indicator-to-a-textarea-controlled-by-javasc/68577054#comment121195141_68576925) however is it still possible to allow selecting?
Or does selecting always come with the compromise of accepting clicks that move the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to have a loop running non stop (with a [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) maybe ?) to add and remove a `|` character every other second, which would simulate the usual text position indicator you have inside most text areas