# Disable cursor clicks without blocking highlighting

Tags: javascript, html, css

> I am making a typewriter-like website ([here](https://docs.thkc.space/cool/typewritter/)) that uses a textarea and javascript (from button clicks) to add/remove from the textarea.

After following these 2 answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68576925/11242524), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68577054/11242524)) I am now using the default typing indicator to show text position.

To prevent users from clicking in other places in the `textarea` I added `pointer-events:none` to the `textarea`'s css, however this also blocks highlighting part or all of the text to manually copy it.

This is the textarea

```html
<textarea id="textarea" class="textarea" data-gramm_editor="false" data-gramm="false">
</textarea>
```

with this css

```css
.textarea {
    pointer-events:none;
    font-size: 23px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    resize: none;
    }
```

Visual explanation: I want to be able to select like [this](https://ali.likes.cash/krpboqkca9a) without being able to click around and do this [this](https://ali.likes.cash/krpbqjep39a).

Is there a way to separate the click and highlighting and only block the clicks?

If a solution won't work smoothly on mobile devices that's still ok just indicate/explain.

Comment: Do you want only visually hide curser or functionality is important , which means that backspace should be disabled!?

Comment: @YasinFarmani
I basically just want the visual properties of the cursor to show where you are without letting you move the cursor around.
However, doing this with `pointer-events:none` prevents highlighting too so I'm looking for a way to only prevent the moving clicks.

Comment: I see, can you change your solution to use editable div and css?

Comment: I didn't understand the question
I haven't ever used content editable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I edited my previous answer:

If I understand correctly you want to keep highlight (select text) but do not let user to move cursor on the textarea. If that is the case, then you can do something like this. First let's remove

```
pointer-events:none;
```

Then add `readonly` on the textarea

example:

```
<textarea readonly id="textarea" class="textarea" data-gramm_editor="false" data-gramm="false">
</textarea>
```

Note: Generally avoid using `pointer-events: none` it will disable highlight and select and also cursor style.

Now in your case (having active select, having cursor active, do not let user move cursor in textarea), you can do something similar to this, you can use a `div` instead of `textarea` and edit inneHTML of that div. As you can see, I created a cursor which is html element and it is similar to a real cursor. By doing this, you have more control on your keyboard, I hope it can help.
Generally it is not possible to achieve all you want with `textarea` only.

```js
const editable = document.getElementById('editableC');

addCursor()

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    removeCursor();
    const letter = event.target.innerHTML;
    if (letter === 'clear') {
      editable.innerHTML = editable.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
    }else {
      editable.innerHTML += letter;
    }
    addCursor()
  })
);


function addCursor(){
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.classList.add('blinking-cursor');
  let text = document.createTextNode('|');
  span.appendChild(text);
  editable.appendChild(span);
}

function removeCursor(){
  const span = editable.querySelector('span')
  span.remove()

}
```

```css
.editableC {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  word-break: break-all;
  
}

.blinking-cursor {
    user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  color:red;
  -webkit-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -moz-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -ms-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  -o-animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
  animation: 1s blink step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: red;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: red;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: red;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: red;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes "blink" {
  from,
  to {
    color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="editableC" class="editableC"></div>

<div style="margin-top:10px">
  <button>A</button>
  <button>B</button>
  <button>clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That removes the cursor entirely which I don't want
I want to have the typing indication so I guess the cursor has to always be at the end to indicate where you are when using the typewriter

Comment: Ah ok, so it is hard to achieve it with textarea, I have one other solution in mind which is combination of contentEditable=true and css but requires some changes in your code.

Comment: What part of the code would need changes?
And would the css break the website layout that is using flexboxes